# How to add add external links in yuidoc (grunt-contrib-yuidoc)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, documentation-generation, yuidoc

I imagine I'm missing something in yuidoc documentation or misunderstanding usage.  I cannot seem to find a way to include a link to an external site/page in my documentation.

In a comment block, I'd like to have something like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a blah-blah for blah-blahing blah.
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @param {object} blah
 *
 * Follow recommendations at:
 * @link <a href="http://blah.com/boop">Boop</a>
 */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According the document says:

> YUIDoc supports 3 main forms of formatting your documentation. HTML, Markdown & Selleck.

So you can use HTML or Markdown like this:

```
/**
 * Creates a blah-blah for blah-blahing blah.
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @param {object} blah
 *
 * Follow recommendations at:
 * <a href="http://blah.com/boop">Boop</a>
 * Or
 * [Boop](http://blah.com/boop)
 * 
 */
```